# unable to get html5's <option> element to display value in PHP

Tags: php, html

Users can choose an item from a category, and update their choices if they choose to do so. I am displaying the items using the `select` element. The items are displayed via php to keep the html code succinct.

```
     <div class="form-group">   
        <label for="category">category</label>
         <select name="category" id="">               
<?php
    getAllCategories();
?>          
         </select>
     </div>
```

getAllCategories is a function stored in a separate file.

```
function getAllCategories() {

global $connection;
$categoryQuery = "SELECT * FROM categories";
$runCategoryQuery = mysqli_query($connection, $categoryQuery);


checkQuery($runCategoryQuery);                               
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runCategoryQuery);

while ($row) {


    $categoryName = $row['category_name'];  
    $categoryId = $row['category_id']; 

    echo "<option value='' name='category_name'> $categoryName </option>";


     $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runCategoryQuery);   
   }
}
```

I am able to display this data correctly. Now if the user wants to change the category, he can click the category section and choose any from the drop-down list. Once he clicks the submit button, the POST request runs.

**problem**: I am unable to get the updated choice of the user, as I get the following message:

```
notice: Undefined index: category_name in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/demo/cms/admin/includes/edit_post.php on line 8
```

The code on that line is :    `$postCategory = $_POST['category_name'];`

`category_name` is defined in the getAllCategories function.

What am I doing wrong?

I've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index), but as I mentioned above, I know what the error means. I have no problem retrieving values from a form or a file. I am having problems with retrieving values from the `select` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if u want to get value of a option in php, then use name of select, not option element

```
$postCategory = $_POST['category_name'];
```

change to

```
$postCategory = $_POST['category'];
```

$postCategory will return value of selected option

function

```
function getAllCategories() {

  global $connection;
  $categoryQuery = "SELECT * FROM categories";
  $runCategoryQuery = mysqli_query($connection, $categoryQuery);


  checkQuery($runCategoryQuery);                               
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runCategoryQuery);

  while ($row) {


      $categoryName = $row['category_name'];  
      $categoryId = $row['category_id']; 

      echo "<option value='".$categoryId."'> $categoryName       </option>";


       $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($runCategoryQuery);   
     }
  }
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it didnt work. Now I do not get an error, but php does not echo anything out either.

Comment: @Frosty619 of course, 'cause u did not give option element any value, so it not gonna echo anything.

Comment: $categoryName = $row['category_name'];  
    $categoryId = $row['category_id']; 

    echo "<option value=' $categoryId'> $categoryName </option>";

Comment: try it in while loop, u will get the category id

Comment: I am not sure I follow. The code you wrote above, I already have in my `getAllCategories` function. Where am I suppose to put your code?

Comment: just replace the echo : echo "<option value='".$categoryId."'> $categoryName </option>";

Comment: Ahh, I get it now. Thank you!